# Angular UI-Router pass stateparam from JSON in repeater

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a repeater for a nav:

```
<div class="list-group left-nav">
    <a ng-repeat="e in departments.leftNav" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="{{e.value}}({department:'hr'})" href="" class="list-group-item" >{{e.label}}</a>
  </div>
```

You'll notice there's a hard-coded string in there, `({department:'hr'})`

Since I originally hard-coded the "hr" string in the SREF, that link works as expected and takes you to the page for HR. What I'd rather do is add another parameter to the JSON file and use **that** in the repeater.

```
    {
  "nav": [{
    "label": "File Transfer - HR",
    "value": "departments.filetransfer",
    "dept": "hr"
  }, {
    "label": "File Transfer - Sales",
    "value": "departments.filetransfer",
    "dept": "sales"
  }]
}
```

So, where it says `ui-sref="{{e.value}}({department:'hr'})"` i need to somehow pull in `{{e.dept}}` but can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: `ui-sref="{{e.value}}({department: e.dept})"` ? Always remember that attributes like these are evaluated using `$scope.$eval(someAttrStringValue)`.

Comment: simpler than I thought!  Thanks.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, you should post this as an answer so he can accept it and close it out.